# Use a Module to return multiple plots

Tags: plotting, scoping

A program I'm running requires me to generate multiple plots over the same domain, so I thought it would be fairly simple to use a module and bury all of the plot commands within that that way I only have to call the function and domain once and I can generate all of my plots without having to go and change the domain every time.

This has worked, but the plots always come out small and inline, and I was wondering if there was a way for me to tell Mathematica I wanted each plot in its own output that way it would be the same size as if I had just called the plot command.

This is what I'm using:

```
Plots[o_,r_,t_ :50]:= Module[{a,b,c,d},
  a = Plot[f1[x],{x,o,r},Ticks->{{t,2t,3t,4t,5t,6t,7t,8t,9t,10t},{0,0.2,0.4,0.6,0.8,1}}, PlotLabel->"Plot1";
  b = Plot[f2[x],{x,o,r},Ticks->{{t,2t,3t,4t,5t,6t,7t,8t,9t,10t},{0,0.2,0.4,0.6,0.8,1}}, PlotLabel->"Plot2";
  c= Plot[f3[x],{x,o,r},Ticks->{{t,2t,3t,4t,5t,6t,7t,8t,9t,10t},{0,0.2,0.4,0.6,0.8,1}}, PlotLabel->"Plot3";
  d=Plot[f4[x],{x,o,r},Ticks->{{t,2t,3t,4t,5t,6t,7t,8t,9t,10t},{0,0.2,0.4,0.6,0.8,1}}, PlotLabel->"Plot4";
  Print[a,b,c,d]
]
```

If anyone has any better suggestions for how I can output my plots I'd greatly appreciate it.

Comment: 1. Use something like `GraphicsGrid`, not `Print`. 2.  Your code is incomplete (perhaps copy-n-paste error), so it's not runnable. 3} Your code is incomplete - what are the definitions of the `f1...`.

Comment: And why do you want to make the range of ticks unrelated to the domain of the function?  If `o = 0`, `r = 1` and `t=50`, then your Ticks go to 500 while the function only goes to `x = 1`.  Please fix your question!

Comment: I would say that the ticks are a trivial, localized side issue to the main question, which seems to be how to get each of several plots in a regular output cell.

Comment: The functions that I'm plotting aren't really relevant to the quesiton which is why I didn't post them. You can insert x, x^2, -x, 1-x for the if you like. Makes no difference.

Comment: I can define t to be whatever i want it just defaults to 50. I have the huge range in ticks that may or may not go beyond my domain I know that my entire domain will be ticked in the incroments that I want. This again isn't really relevant to my question, just a personal preference for how I want my graphs displayed

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`CellPrint`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CellPrint.html) together with [`ExpressionCell`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ExpressionCell.html):

```
Plots[o_, r_, t_ : 50] := 
 Module[{a, b, c, d}, 
  a = Plot[f1[x], {x, o, r}, 
    Ticks -> {{t, 2 t, 3 t, 4 t, 5 t, 6 t, 7 t, 8 t, 9 t, 10 t}, {0, 
       0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1}}, PlotLabel -> "Plot1"];
  b = Plot[f2[x], {x, o, r}, 
    Ticks -> {{t, 2 t, 3 t, 4 t, 5 t, 6 t, 7 t, 8 t, 9 t, 10 t}, {0, 
       0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1}}, PlotLabel -> "Plot2"];
  c = Plot[f3[x], {x, o, r}, 
    Ticks -> {{t, 2 t, 3 t, 4 t, 5 t, 6 t, 7 t, 8 t, 9 t, 10 t}, {0, 
       0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1}}, PlotLabel -> "Plot3"];
  d = Plot[f4[x], {x, o, r}, 
    Ticks -> {{t, 2 t, 3 t, 4 t, 5 t, 6 t, 7 t, 8 t, 9 t, 10 t}, {0, 
       0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1}}, PlotLabel -> "Plot4"];
  CellPrint@ExpressionCell[#, "Output"] & /@ {a, b, c, d};
  ]
```

Example:

```
Block[{f1 = Sin, f2 = Exp[#/20] - 1 &, f3 = #^3/1000 &, f4 = Tan[#]/10 &},
 Plots[0, 10, 1]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Try `Block[{f1 = Sin, f2 = Exp[#/20] - 1 &, f3 = #^3/1000 &, 
  f4 = Tan[#]/10 &}, Plots[0, 10, 50]]` to see that the result is surely not what the question poser seeks.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Why would you use a default tick spacing of 50 on a domain of length 10?  I figure that's why the OP made `t` an argument.  I think the OP probably does want 50 because it makes sense for his or her typical domain & units.   I also figure that the vertical ticks makes sense because the OP is plotting concentrations or something like that.  I just didn't want to fuss too much figuring out suitable test functions simply for a proof-of-concept example.

Comment: @CosmoSounder BTW, the use of the variables `a`, `b`, `c`, `d` is unnecessary in the code sample.  One can directly print a cell with something like `CellPrint@ExpressionCell[Plot[...], "Output"];` for each plot.

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming your inclusion of `t` is an error.  There is no reason you would want the range of ticks to be unrelated to the domain of your plots.  (Your question would allow the plot to be between x = 0 and x = 1 and your `Ticks` go up to 500, for instance.)  Perhaps you want to set *number* of ticks to be `t`.

Here's what I *think* you want:

```
f[x_] := {x^2, x^3, x^4, x^5};
myPlots[o_, r_, t_: 50] := Module[{ },
  SetOptions[Plot, ImageSize -> 200, 
   Ticks -> {N@Range[o, r, (r - o)/t], Range[0, 1, .2]}];
  Row[Table[Plot[f[x][[i]], {x, o, r}], {i, 1, 4}]]];

myPlots[0, 1, 10]
```

[image]